# facing error during rebuild project

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

Comment: post your manifest and gradle

Comment: @AbhinavGupta concerning your current edit-activity: would you please note that code-markdown ist for code only, not for product-names or random technical terms. Please don't ruin posts by adding tons of wrong backticks....

Comment: @AbhinavGupta please use the backticks only for code - "sqlite" is a product name, not code. "QR code" is a technical term, not code etc...

Comment: @piet.t OK I will remember for the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `multiDexEnabled true;` in  defaultConfig of `Gradle` file as

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Your app Id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true;
}
```

and add compile `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in dependencies